# How to read this in simple English?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

$∃x.P(x) \Rightarrow ∀x.P(x) $

How can I read this in simple English? I translated it as: There exists an element x for which P(x) implies that for all elements x, P(x) is true - but I feel like this doesn't make much sense. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It  makes sense. It says that if there is one element satisfying the property $P$ then all elements under consideration satisfy the property $P$. I'll try and give an example: on the battlefield, soldiers are encouraging each other, and one says : "if one of us dies, then all of us will die". If $P(x)$ is the property :" the soldier is dead",  and $x$ runs through all the soldiers, then we see that the statement : "if one of us dies, then all of us will die" translates to $\exists x P(x) \implies \forall x P(x)$ (Sorry if my example is a little rusty).

Comment: You are welcome, @ZE16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\exists x P(x)$ is read as

> there exists $x$ such that $P(x)$ holds

Likewise $\forall x P(x)$ is read as

> for every $x$, $P(x)$ holds.

$A \implies B$ is read as

> If $A$ then $B$.

Thus, bringing all of this together, $\exists x P(x) \implies \forall x P(x)$ is read as

> If there exists $x$ such that $P(x)$, then $P(x)$ holds for every $x$.

Which is the same as what you have.

Answer (score 0):

Your translation is right: suppose that there is an element $x$ that makes $P(x)$ true. Then all elements make $P(x)$ true.

This does sound a little weird, but just because it is weird, that doesn't make the translation incorrect. (Logic is pretty weird.) There are predicates $P(x)$ that make $\exists x. P(x) \Rightarrow \forall x. P(x)$ true. One possible $P(x)$ is a predicate that doesn't actually depend on $x$, such as the statement '2+2=4'. Do you see how $\exists x. P(x) \Rightarrow \forall x. P(x)$ is true for this $P(x)$?

Comment: Yes, thank you!